# How to monitor users in forum page

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Is there a way to monitor a users activities in a particular web page? What I want to do is to see if a particular user is currently active in a forum, and if not active, the user should be displayed as absent from forum

```
 $sql   =   "SELECT * FROM forumlog WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id'];
 $result    =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
        $sql   = "INSERT INTO forumlog (course_id, user_id, log_time)
                VALUES(
                ".$_GET['course_id'].",
                ".$_SESSION['user_id'].",
                ".time().")";
       $result    =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The above code is what I use to log the user into the forum, this is because the forum is just a page on my site, and until the user clicks on the forum link he would not be logged in, but then I don't how to go about logging out the user from the forum page or checking to see if the user is active in that forum

Comment: just as a side note, look into stopping your use of mysql_query, use PDO of mysqli_query instead as mysql_query is now deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: yeah, thanks I would work on that

Comment: Think you will just have to check for users where the log_time for that user is within X mins (assuming you update the log_time each time they do anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could go through a little stress you could make an open connection to the server using polling, and return an array position of the mouse for a span of 30 seconds, if the position remains the same with previous 30 seconds then you would conclude the user is not currently active. and could make a script to log the user out..... well, am just saying....

Answer (score 3):

When user enters page you can put the time in database. Everytime he refreshes page you should update this time.

To check which users are active you must select from database users that "time" is less than 5 minutes.

To check what users are absent you need to check users than time is greater than 5 minutes.

5 minutes of course can be changed to value you want.

If you want to be more particular you can name actions on your website and put it to database in structure like:

```
id, user_id, datetime, action, params
```

and put records

```
1, NOW(), 4,  "viewforum", "forum_id=4,post_id=6"
```

and then you can select activites in last 5 minutes and check by user_id who is online.

Comment: The thing is I am making over 90% of the forum page asynchronous, so the only time the user refreshes the page is when the is trying to leave the forum page

Comment: asynchronous request are handled by server which can update database.

Comment: so for every activity then I would have a code that updates that database column?

Comment: if you want to monit every activity then yes, if you want to see only if user is active then you should update 1 field for example in users_table as Mr Alien suggested during every user activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, have a `last_seen` column in your DB, probably users column

Now Log the login activity of the user, when user switch between forum pages, keep updating the `last_seen` column, now to detect whether the user is online or offline you need to subtract the `last_seen time` from `current time`

```
if(strtotime($current_time) - strtotime($last_seen) < 60) { //60 Seconds /1 minute
   echo 'User Is Online';
} else {
   echo 'User Is Offline';
}
/* This will mark users online if they 
   were active before a minute, certainly you can extend it to 2-3 minutes  
   i.e 120/180 sec */
```

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way of doing this has already been explained (updating the "last_activity" field every time the user loads some content).

I'm going to point a totally different way of doing this: **websockets**.

As you know `http` works in a request-response way. Connection is created by the client, and closed after a response has been sent (well, not always, depending on keepalive). So your problem ("*how can I know if the user is still there?*") just can't be solved unless you accept this: "*if the user is not requesting more content, consider he's not online anymore*".

Well, websockets have an advantage here, as the connection is not closed until the client or the server decide it's time to disconnect. So you can open a connection when the user enters the forum, and leave it there until the client leaves the page or closes the browser and thus the connection is closed.

The bad news: you have to write a server that listens for those connections. For example using Node.js. It's not difficult, but you need root access to the server, and then write a few lines of code.

The traditional way is easier, it's just an sql query, but it's good to know about alternatives.

**edit**

#### Quick example

1. Install Node.js: http://nodejs.org/
2. Install socket.io (it's a node.js module): http://socket.io/
3. Write a simple server like this:

```js
var socketsConnected = 0;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socketsConnected++;
    // send him some information
    socket.emit('totalSocketsOnline', { counter: socketsConnected });
    // let the others know that the counter has changed!
    socket.broadcast.emit('totalSocketsOnline', { counter: socketsConnected });

    // socket events
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("Socket disconnected");
        socketsConnected--;
        // again, notify all clients!
        socket.broadcast.emit('totalSocketsOnline', { counter: socketsConnected });
    });
});
```

4- Write a simple client like this:

```js
<script src="http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://yourdomain.com:8080');
    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        // connected, we are so happy...
    });
    socket.on('totalSocketsOnline', function (data) {
        // wohohoo lets show how many sockets we have online now
        alert("We have "+data['counter']+" sockets online now!");
    });
</script>
```

I've just coded that, so it will probably contain errors and won't work, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Do you have links that would take me where to learn how to work that, it sounds nice. Thanks..

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example. But there are lots of good tutorials for Node.js out there.

Comment: Thanks so much, this would  go a long way

Comment: It's just an example, it is possible that you don't want to count "sockets" and instead count "users". And it's possible that you don't want to count "guests". Also if a user leaves the browser open for 1h, you probably would like the server to close the connection... so take it easy, you can improve it a lot hehe.

Comment: It's also worth bearing in mind that Web Sockets aren't supported by quite a large percentage of browsers, I would consider implementing something to fall back on should they be unavailable.